# Download image without watermark

Tags: media

I have a content type that includes an image field. After the image is uploaded, I add a watermark to this field using the Imagecache Actions module.

I would like to allow users to download the image without watermark. Is it possible?

Comment: Please tell us how do you add a watermark. I readily know 3 ways to do it, from "Drupal way" with Image Styles to server script way that's probably more efficient if you think about response times and CPU. I bet it's styles but I'd like it confirmed. If so, you just need another style without watermark. If not, we need to know more. And why to watermark pictures if people should be free to download unmarked ones anyway?

Comment: In the future I want to allow user to download image after buying it. But now, I want to do small step and I want to do what I written. I add watermark with Imagecache Actions module.

Answer (score 5):

Before watermarking the image, store the original copy in another, [private file mode](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file) image field.

Then you can control access to the original image with [hook_file_download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7).

Comment: You can also accomplish essentially the same thing by using the Media module, and then you can field your image with the non-watermarked image.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I know nothing about controlling access with hook_file_download. I tried to read something, yet I don't understand it. Could you tell me more?